# Why is "Search pattern not terminated" in this snippet?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to update a piece of code to remove any non-alphanumeric character, assign the resultant string to a new variable, and rewrite my HTML to include that value in a new meta tag:

```
if ( $main::url =~ m/index:Devices/ )
{
    my $prodname = getMetaValue(\$doc,'Product_Name');
    $prodname =~ tr/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ];
    $strippedname =~ $prodname;
    $doc =~ s{</head>}{<meta name='Stripped_Name' content='$strippedname' />\n</head>}is;
}
```

The last line throws a "Search pattern not terminated" error, and I can't figure out why. I use a similar method that does work elsewhere in the script:

```
if ( $main::url =~ m/index:Devices/ )
{
    my $prodname = getMetaValue(\$doc,'Product_Name');
    my $brandname = getMetaValue(\$doc,'Manufacturer_Name');
    my $devicefullname = $brandname.' '.$prodname;
    $doc =~ s{</head>}{<meta name='Device_Full_Name' content='$devicefullname' />\n</head>}is;
}
```

Any idea why the special character removal script fails me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of the `tr` operator is `tr/CHARS/REPLACEMENT/`.  Further, it performs a *transliteration* (not regex match) which normally replaces the given *literal* characters, and in a rather particular way.

But you *can* do what you want with `tr`, as it allows ranges and has `/c`  modifier (*complement*)

```
$prodname =~ tr/a-zA-Z0-9 //dc;
```

From [Quote-Like-Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)

> If the /c modifier is specified, the SEARCHLIST character set is complemented.

However, using `tr///` (specially with `/c`) is a bit obscure in comparison with using `s///`, which you also utilize later in the code. Use of `s///` would make it clearer

```
$prodname =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]//g;
```

The modifier `/g` makes it remove *all* occurences of characters specified by  `[^...]`.

The regex itself can also be written as

```
s/[^a-z0-9 ]//gi;
```

but see *Negation* [in perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes) for notes on  using `/i` with negated class and unicode. For an efficiency improvement we can add the `+` quantifier, `s/[...]+//gi`, as all occurences need be removed anyway. Note that the `tr///` should be *much* faster here.

With *POSIX character classes* this can be written as   `s/[^[:alnum:] ]//g;`

Answer (score 2):

`tr///` needs three instances of the delimiter, not just one.

```
$prodname =~ tr/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ];
```

Moreover, `[` means the literal square bracket in `tr`. Maybe you wanted `m//` or `s///`?